# select dropdown replacement

Tags: select, drop-down-menu

i have a plain dropdown list (html ) that looks pretty simple. It is a list of countries and i need to add the flag inside the select . Is there a nice jquery replacement out there?

Something like http://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/ could work (check out the currency list).

Thanks.

Comment: That currency selector is not a normal HTML select.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JavaScript image combobox](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) which works with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well this works, but Janko Jovanovic posted this solution a couple years ago and it even includes the flags: [Reinventing a Drop Down with CSS and jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)